# How to re-enable my Facebook account?

Tags: facebook

My Facebook account got disabled without any prior warning. I have been using account for 3 and a half years without any issue.

I have raised several appeals to Facebook help center, even emailed them on *appeals@Facebook* but got response as *You've reached us at a channel that we don't support.*

Please suggest me how to get my account enabled again. How do I reach the Facebook team directly?

Answer (score 2):

Submit your appeal via their [Appeals Contact page](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/260749603972907).